# Django redirect doesn't work in class based view

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a class based view which i am checking some conditions and redirecting to another page, i see the GET request to that page in the terminal and it returns 200, but it doesn't redirect to the page:

```
class CheckoutFinalView(CartOrderMixin, View):
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    order_obj = None
    if cart_obj.items.count() == 0:
        return redirect("carts:cart")
    billing_profile, billing_profile_created = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)
    has_card = False
    if billing_profile is not None:
        order_obj, order_obj_created = Order.objects.new_or_get(billing_profile, cart_obj)
        order_obj.save()
        has_card = billing_profile.has_card
    is_prepared = order_obj.check_done()
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    if is_prepared:
        print(is_prepared)
        did_charge, crg_msg = billing_profile.charge(order_obj)
        print(did_charge)
        if did_charge:
            order_obj.mark_paid()  # sort a signal for us
            request.session['cart_items'] = 0
            del request.session['cart_id']
            del request.session["order_id"]
            if not billing_profile.user:
                print("not billing profile user: ", billing_profile.user)
                billing_profile.set_cards_inactive()
            return redirect("checkout_final")
        else:
            print(crg_msg)
            return redirect("checkout_final")

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return redirect("carts:success")
```

I tried `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('carts:success'))` , too. But it doesn't work, too.

Comment: You here only redirect a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

> I see the GET request to that page in the terminal and it returns 200.

That is perfectly normal, you only specify to redirect for a POST request, since you override `def post`.

You thus should implement it for a GET request with:

```
class CheckoutFinalView(CartOrderMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return redirect('carts:success')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       return redirect('carts:success')
```

Note that this view however does not *do* much, it simply redirects. In that case, you can make use of a `RedirectView`:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class CheckoutFinalView(RedirectView):
    url = reverse_lazy('carts:success')
```